# Store input field value in session without form submit

Tags: php, html, session, input

How can I store input field value in session without form submit?

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" />
```

Comment: you need jQuery to do that..

Comment: use AJAX to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not interact directly with the browser. You'll need to use `javascript` to obtain the value of the `textbox` and then append it to the `url` **(GET OR POST).**

I don't understand why you cannot use a `form` - they're there for the purpose of passing data to pages.

**PHP is server side,** as in once the page has been sent to the browser from the server, PHP is useless and has no control. PHP can process forms, use variables etc.

`Javascript` is the opposite. It only works once the page is sent and is entirely reliant on the browser. It can be used to auto fill forms and even submit forms for you. Because it is browser dependant, if your visitor has turned off javascript, is will not work at all.

AJAX is between these forms, so it can auto submit forms, process variables etc... It's 
simply an extension of javascript, so if you know javascript, AJAX isn't that much more work.